# MySQL table partial redundancy

Tags: mysql

I am finding pair of roommates along with room information. 
currently I can get a table like below

example:

```
- Id1 Id2 Dorm room
- 101 133  2a   1
- 121 154  1b   3
- 218 584  3a   2
- 133 101  2a   1
- 584 218  3a   2
- 154 121  1b   3
```

not sure how to clear the redundancy as I want a table like this

```
- Id1 Id2 Dorm  room
- 101 133  2a    1
- 154 121  1b    3
- 218 584  3a    2
```

I was starting with a table like this

```
- StuID Dorm  room
- 101    2a    1
- 154    1b    3
- 121    1b    3
- ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, does the order in which you return the roommates matter (e.g. must it be 101 133 2a 1 Or, would 133 101 2a 1 also be acceptable)?

Comment: don't use an equality on the join, just use a >.

Comment: To Ben: no, it doesnt matter. I just need to find distinct pairs of roommates

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an equals on the join for studentID, instead use `<` *or* `>`.

This will really only work if each room can have 1 or 2 roommates.  if a 3rd is present a different solution would have to be generated.

```
SELECT T1.StuID, T2.StuID, T1.Dorm, T1.Room
FROM table T1
LEFT JOIN Table T2
 on T1.Dorm = T2.Dorm 
and T1.Room = T2.Room
and T1.StuID < T2.StuID
```

This forces the T1.StudentID to be less than the T2.StudentID, thus the lower ID student will always be first ensuring order and no duplication.

Left join was used as I was unsure if some rooms only had 1 person and I assumed you wanted those.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! BTW just curious what should I use if there are more than two people sharing one room? Even thats not the case for my question.

Comment: That would depend on several factors, like do you need to display all those names? how many people could be in a room (unlimited?)   If only 4 to a room you could simply add and T2.StuID < T3.StuID and T3.StuID < T4.StuID but that will still result in T1 being tied to T3 and T4  So I'd probably revisit the solution and use a user variable to add a derived row number to each record for each dorm/room and then use a case statement to determine what column to display each name... something like `max(CASE when RN = 1 then T1.STuID end), ... and then group by room, student.

Comment: Window functions in other databases; such as `Row_number() over (partition by dorm,room order by StuID)` can simulated in mySQL using user variables.  These allow us to generate  row number for each student in a dorm/room combo and then we can use those row numbers to assign each student to a separate column in the result set.  if we have a constant number (say 4) we could simulate a `Pivot` statement to switch the rows to columns. but that requires a known upper limit of students per room.

Comment: that is really helpful! Thank you